# max and min values from json in d3

Tags: json, svg, d3.js

I'm following a tutorial of d3 that uses tsv rather than json.
I'm more familiar with json so I wanted to apply my own json object to the example.

I found this and tried to apply it but i'm still getting errors:
[How to use d3.min and d3.max within a d3.json command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488194/how-to-use-d3-min-and-d3-max-within-a-d3-json-command)

Here is my code. I am getting the json object back with my first log. And the correct length with my second log.

Yet I get this error when trying to use d.value in d3.max()
Error: Invalid value for  attribute width="NaN"

```
d3.json("sampledata.json", function(error, data) {

            var maxx = d3.entries(data)
                .sort(function(a,b){return d3.descending(a.value, b.value);})

            console.log(maxx)

            console.log(data.length);
            mydata = data;
            x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })])


chart.attr("height", barHeight * mydata.length);

var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
    .data(mydata)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

// WHERE MY ERROR IS because there is no value for x
bar.append("rect")
    .attr("width", x)
    .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

bar.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d) - 3; })
    .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

});
```

Comment: Sorry. Here's the JSON:[
    {"value": 1},
    {"value": 2},
    {"value": 10},
    {"value": 12},
    {"value": 33},
    {"value": 41},
    {"value": 55}

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to do, since `x` is a scale of some kind, is the following:

```
bar.append("rect")
    .attr("width", function(d) {
       return x(d.value);
    })
    .attr("height", barHeight - 1);
```

Otherwise it is just going to pass `d` into `x`, which isn't going to help you.

Comment: But isn't this: x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]) doing that for me in a sense...the domain attribute?

Comment: All you're doing there is giving it the min and max, not telling it how to search the input. Your domain has no prior knowledge of the data structure, nor should it.

Comment: A helpful site for beginners in addition to the one d3 provided: http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/scales