# Javascript: Find a key with maximum value in a object after filtering keys based on an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

My js object:

```
data_obj = {'p1': 1, 'p2':2, 'p3':3}
```

my array

```
data_array = ['p1', 'p3']
```

Now, I want to filter the object based on the array. Expected result is

```
fil_obj = {'p1': 1, 'p3':3}
```

Now then, find the key having a maximum value. Expected result is

```
p3
```

Since I have object with thousands of items, I expect a very efficient solution. 
Since I'm using d3js for this project, solution based on d3js like d3.max would be great.

Comment: *"I expect a very efficient solution"* - What's your solution?

Comment: Just write a program to do this.

Comment: Maybe this answer can halp you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488194/how-to-use-d3-min-and-d3-max-within-a-d3-json-command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the wanted properties and return the max key.

```js
var data_obj = { p1: 1, p2: 2, p3: 3},
    data_array = ['p1', 'p3'],
    result = data_array.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        return !i || data_obj[r] < data_obj[a] ? a : r;
    }, undefined);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I thought the filtered object was also a required output. I guess not. Nice solution for just the key.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used d3, but it seems to me you can get the result pretty efficiently with a single call to `.reduce()`:

```js
var data_obj = {'p1': 1, 'p2':2, 'p3':3};
var data_array = ['p1', 'p3'];

var results = data_array.reduce((r,v)=>{
  if (v in data_obj) {
    r.data[v] = data_obj[v];
    if (data_obj[v] > r.maxVal) {
      r.maxKey = v;
      r.maxVal = data_obj[v];
    }
  }
  return r;
}, {data:{}, maxKey:null, maxVal:Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY});

console.log(results);
```